# Cannot call input$"OptionType1"

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to create dynamic UI in my Shiny app. I increment a variable (dealNumber) every time I add an input via a button. However, I need to get the values from these new inputs. I add the value of dealNumber to the IDs of each input. However, I am having a hard time extracting the values.

```
#I use the following code to create a new input
#dealNumber = 1

column(2,selectInput(paste("optionType",dealNumber,sep=""), label = h5(""),choices = option_type, selected = 1)

#I then need to assign the value from the input above to the variable OptionType. If i use input$"OptionType1" or input$OptionType1 it works. But I need to get the number 1 via a variable so that the code is dynamic.
#I have tried the code below without any sucess

assign("OptionType",input$paste("OptionType",dealNumber,sep=""),.GlobalEnv)
```

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: Use `input[["OptionType1"]]` to archieve this.

Comment: Solved. Gregor thank you so much. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want to pass a string variable as an "argument" to the `input` object to retrieve a value. This can be achieved with `input[["myString"]]`.

To illustrate how to use this for dynamically allocated ids, see the following example.

```
create_slider <- function(i) {
  sliderId <- paste0("slider", i)
  sliderInput(sliderId, sliderId, 0, 1, 0)
}

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    create_slider(1),
    create_slider(2),
    create_slider(3),
    numericInput("get_id", "get value of slider", 1, 1, 3, 1),
    textOutput("text")
  ),
  function(input, output, session) {
    output$text <- renderText({
      input[[ paste0("slider", input$get_id) ]]
    })
  }
)
```

In general, I would advise against using `assign` for this purpose. Instead, use a functional logic to capture the inputs from `dealNumber`.

```
getDynamicInput <- function(dealNumber, input) {
  input[[ paste0("optionType", dealNumber) ]]
}
```

Always keep in mind, that the ids you are constructing must be unique
and valid `HTML` ids (no spaces!). Therefore, `paste0` is very useful in such instances.

Maybe you should consider using [shiny-modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) to programatically 
assign `input` slots in order to avoid tedious string-parsing on the server side.